# How can I use make HTTP calls to an API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, http, request

How can I use public APIs in a Javascript application? For example I want to make a call to the Zillow API using JQuery AJAX.
When issuing the request in JQuery AJAX (shown below) I get the following error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "MY HTTP REQUEST URL". Origin "MY WEB DOMAIN" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
var requesturl = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRegionChildren.htm?zws-id="+zwsid+"&state="+state+"&city="+city+"&childtype=neighborhood";
```

Code:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({  
url: requesturl
})
.done(function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

I've also tried adding crossDomain, dataType and headers params (shown below), but they haven't helped.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({  
url: requesturl,
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'xml',
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
beforeSend: setHeader
})
.done(function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [Please explain JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/417685)

Answer (score 0):

Most popular public API's support JSONP request. Refer API documentation for details.

Cross ajax domain request is restricted. So you will be needing to make JSONP request. Don't worry JQuery will handle most of it.

Comment: Well, JSONP works if the service that you're calling supports it.  A service just doesn't provide data in a JSONP-friendly format.

Comment: What can be done if JSONP requests aren't supported? It seems like only XML responses are allowed in this case

Comment: IMHO Instead of hacking around the browsers server side code will be most suitable.

Comment: OK thanks, do you know of any examples of a such a thing done in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to register your url with Zillow, maybe contact them / hunt around on their doc pages. Also jquery has a [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method which makes ajax requests even simpler. There's also [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if that is the return format.